# SharePoint Online and Business Intelligence

Tags: sharepoint-online, performancepoint, office-365, business-intelligence

Is it possible to create a Business Intelligence Center Site Collection in SharePoint Online? Is Performance Point available for SharePoint Online? Where do I find more info about SharePoint Online and Business Intelligence?

Thanks,

Douglas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SharePoint Online does not support much BI features at this moment. Here is some more info on the subject:

http://alanwhitehouse.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/office-365-and-business/

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/8112.aspx